# Error occurs when retrieving column values from a DataTable LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

#### Question 1:

I am writing a query to get the index of a row in a DataTable:

```
var index = from row in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
let r = row.Field<string>("Column1") 
where r == strColumn1 
select DataTable1.Rows.IndexOf(row);
```

Then I am trying to do it for multiple columns

```
var index = from row in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
let r = row.Field<string>("Column1") && s = row.Field<int>("Column2")
&& t = row.Field<string>("Column3") && u = row.Field<string>("Column4")
where r == strColumn1 && s == intColumn2 && t == strColumn3 && u == strColumn4
select DataTable1.Rows.IndexOf(row);
```

Is it possible?

#### Question 2:

From the answer by [@DominicZukiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797424/128444) When using `let` on multiple columns like this, I am getting an error:

```
var index = from row in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
let r = row.Field<string>("Column1")
let s = row.Field<int>("Column2")
let t = row.Field<string>("Column3")
let u = row.Field<string>("Column4")
where r == strColumn1 && s == intColumn2 && t == strColumn3 && u == strColumn4
select DataTable1.Rows.IndexOf(row);

DataTable1.Rows[index]["Columnx"] = intUpdateValueColumnx;
DataTable1.Rows[index]["Columny"] = intUpdateValueColumny;
DataTable1.Rows[index]["Columnz"] = intUpdateValueColumnz;
DataTable1.AcceptChanges();
```

This comes in the form of:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @cahmad: Please can you *not* update your question after answers have been presented, to then include more questions. You can cross-relate them in another question, but it means the answers get out of sync with the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `let` for each assignment you require:

```
var index = from row in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
   let r = row.Field<string>("Column1")
   let s = row.Field<int>("Column2")
   let t = row.Field<string>("Column3")
   let u = row.Field<string>("Column4")
   where r == strColumn1 && s == intColumn2 && t == strColumn3 && u == strColumn4
   select DataTable1.Rows.IndexOf(row);
```

--

As you have updated your question, I am updated my answer accordingly:

The error looks like there is a problem converting the `s` parameter, because it cannot convert it to an `System.Int32`.

Are you sure that "Column2" is actually an integer?

Comment: you unable to update as below like DataTable1.Rows[index]["Columnx"] = intUpdateValue;
DataTable1.Rows[index]["Coumny"] = intUpdateValue;
DataTable1.AcceptChanges();

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: you cannot do like DataTable1.Rows[index]["Columnx"] = intUpdateValue; DataTable1.Rows[index]["Coumny"] = intUpdateValue; DataTable1.AcceptChanges();. So what is the value of index actually?

Comment: `.IndexOf()` gets you the row number of the specified row in the `DataTable`. From your question, I don't know the context of why you want it, but this is the solution for what you are asking for.